# Error installing nopCommerce 2.65

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce

While installing nopCommerce 2.65 I am getting following error
**"•Setup failed: Sequence contains more than one element"**

I am entering setup information with DB connection information but I am getting this error.

Kindly help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the best place to ask this question is on the **nopCommerce forum** !!! **http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/default.aspx**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you upgrading, or doing a fresh install? If you've had a failed install, it's not uncommon to get that message. If it's a failed install, delete the previous database that was created, and re-install - it should go fine after that.